# Need help uploading a paper with image files to arXiv & journal submission pages

Tags: graphics, lyx, arxiv

Just to be clear:

1. Anything that goes beyond Kindergarten-level computering is going to *whoosh* straight over my head, so please, be gentle.
2. I am a Macintosh/Apple user.
3. I am essentially TeX illiterate, having adapted to using my beloved LyX's button- and menu-based interface, along with an array of hotkey commands.

So far, here is the method I have been using to insert images into my documents.

Example:

There is a file on my desktop called `TakagiCurve.png`.

In my LyX software, I go to **Insert** on the drop-down menu, select **Graphics**, select **Browse** on the pop-up that appears, and then choose `TakagiCurve.png`. I then adjust the size of the image in the document accordingly. Having done so, I use my cursor to highlight the image in the document, and then go to the **Insert** drop-down menu again and select **Float** and the **Figure**.

I should mention that if I put the `TakagiCurve.png` image file in a folder, LyX is unable to locate the image and I have to re-select the image using **Browse** in order to get it to display once more in LyX and on the PDF that LyX churns out for me.

To upload my paper to arXiv, I go to the **File** dropdown menu on LyX, select **Export** and then select **LaTeX (pdflatex)**, which is the format that arXiv says I should use to upload the TeX code when images are present.

I then upload the TeX code file, along with the image file `TakagiCurve.png`. However, when I proceed to have arXiv begin its automatic processing feature, it terminates, reporting an error that the image `TakagiCurve.png` cannot be found:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `TakagiCurve' not
> found.

I have read arXiv's FAQ about common causes of this problem, and their explanations are completely over my head. I would very much appreciate help in learning how to upload papers with images in them; I assume that once I know how to do it for arXiv, I will be able to do it for pretty much any mathematical journal submission process. Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

UPDATE:

I have tried submitting it with my image files, but with the TeX code uploaded as **LaTeX (plain)** rather than **LateX (pdflatex)**. It still fails to process my document, giving the same error message as before:

> ​ ! LaTeX Error: File `TakagiCurve' not found.

Here is the relevant code from the plain LaTeX file exported by LyX:

```
A parabola occurs for $w=1/4$, a result of Archimedes. \begin{center}
\begin{figure} \begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{TakagiCurve} \par\end{centering}
\caption{The blancmange curve $T_{1/2}\left(x\right)$ on
$\left[-1,1\right]$} \end{figure} \par\end{center}
```

Comment: Are you sure that on arxiv pdflatex is used and not latex?

Comment: Yes. 

They say: "Your submission to the archive must be in one of the following formats (listed in order of preference):
(La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, PDFLaTeX
PDF
PostScript
HTML with JPEG/PNG/GIF images" However, I will try using ordinary LaTex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried it using LaTeX (plain), but it still produced an error. I have updated my post to include the error message produced by arXiv's processing software in this instance.

Comment: Could you generate a minimal TeX file that includes a single image, and post it here? If for example it’s hardcoding the full instead of the relative path to your image, that’d tell us.

Comment: `\includegraphics[scale=0.15,Help]{TakagiCurve}` -- the `Help` thing is wrong there.

Comment: Open the tex file exported by lyx in some editor and try to find the code for the graphic so that you can show it.

Comment: I removed the "help" that shouldn't have been there. that was something I accidentally wrote out of a cry for help. xD Anyhow, I've copied the code from the file produced by LaTeX and placed it in my post.

Comment: By experience I know very well that uploading to arXiv can be a nightmare, so let me ask: are you sure that the missing file error is the _first_ error you get?

Comment: @campa Yes. I use the Command-F search for "error", and the first error to appear is indeed the one indicated above, that the Takagi Curve image file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PNG figure files in latex format so you *must* use pdflatex (latex requires postscript-type figures).

To produce a package that arXiv can understand you'll want to make use of the **Export** function under the **File** menu and select `LaTeX (pdflatex)`. This will create a pdflatex version of the file in the same directory as your `.lyx` file. However, in LyX, it doesn't generate relative linking to your figure if it is not in a completely different file location than your `.lyx` file (*i.e.* it will place the full path to the figure file into its `\includegraphics` directive, which will fail in arXiv). So before you place the graphic into your document, you should make sure that it's on the same "relative path" as the `.lyx` file. So for example if you have your paper in a folder called "Paper", all your graphics should be under that same directory. This might look something like:

```
Paper/
Paper/Myfile.lyx
Paper/figure.png
```

So then when you export your project it will create the `Myfile.tex` that you can upload to arXiv along with `figure.png`.

Lastly, if you're having an issue specific to an arXiv submission, your best bet is to [contact arXiv help](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) with your specific `submit-id`, and then one of the admins can assist you with your specific example. Based on your description, I suspect that the issue is that your source is using the full path to the file (something like `/Users/[myName]/Desktop/TakagiCurve.png`).